# add Int number in string

Tags: swift

I want to add random Int number in my variable I tried `var playerCard = "card" + String(a)` also `var playerCard = "card\(a)"` but I get the same error. btw im just a beginner learning basics.

every solution will be appericated <3

```swift
@State var a = Int.random(in: 1...10)
@State var playerCard = "card" + String(a)
```

Comment: *"but I get the same error"*... what is the exact error?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to do this? When the `View` is created? After a button is pressed? Will it happen once, or multiple times based on some condition?

Comment: When you ask a question, stop to think: "Am I providing enough information for my readers to know what is going on and help me fix it?" You said "but I get the same error." Did you tell your readers what error you are getting? Did you make it clear what you mean by "the same error"? The same as what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have executable code, like `"card" + String(a)`, directly in the property declaration... unless you use a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259).

So, you can replace `@State var playerCard = "card" + String(a)` with something like this:

```
var playerCard: String { /// this is a computed property!
   "card" + String(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some explanation of *why* you need a computed property:

in Swift you don't have to use `self` when accessing properties except when the compiler requires it. Write out your declarations in full with `self`

```swift
@State var a = Int.random(in: 1...10)
@State var playerCard = "card" + String(self.a)
```

The problem is that `self` in `self.a`, doesn't exist yet. You cannot access self until all the objects properties have been initialised, and since `playerCard` is a property, it cannot be initialised, so the object cannot be initialised.